# Let English English you

Tags: meaning

Today I saw an advertisement saying, "Let English English you." Near the second *English*, there were *own*.

What does this phrase really mean? Is it just a slogan? (This is an advertisement of an English school.)

Comment: What's this ad promoting? Where did this ad come from?

Comment: I think this is too localized.

Comment: Even "just a slogan" should ordinarily mean *something*. Your example doesn't seem to mean anything. Can you give any more context?

Comment: @FumbleFingers it was The ad. no more. Ad of an English school.

Comment: @igor: Without more, we can't interpret this for you.

Comment: @simchona so do I. That is why I asked and was punished. :) Very good site, too localized for me.

Comment: @igor: We cannot see the ad; we can only know what you tell us of it. Unfortunately in this case, we were unable to fully help.

Comment: @igor: I seriously suggest you don't enrol in that school!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree :)

Comment: @igor: Most of your questions here on ELU are quite reasonable, and I hope the answers have been helpful. But I do think one area you need to be careful of is asking the meaning of "sentences" which you think *may not have been produced by native English speakers*. In this case the sentence was not your own, and it was closed as "too localised". If you submit sentences which you yourself have created, to ask if they are okay, they may get closed as "proofreading". Also, please do understand why we often ask for "more context".

Comment: @igor: I understand your frustration (but not your last sentence! :) I cannot upvote this question because it is a *bad* one by ELU standards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

["English"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/English) as a verb, is very rare. Personally, I've never heard of such a usage, but looking it up on the dictionary, I find:

> English v. to adopt (a foreign word) into English

In the context of the ad, instead of adopting a foreign **word**, "English" is used to mean, adopt **you** into English, that is, make you more ... Western perhaps? More Anglicized.

Then, the punchline. "Own" means to have complete control over, or complete possessorship over something. Meaning, don't just let English adopt you, let it possess you completely.

I am supposing, presuming, that this ad is an advertisement promoting English.

Comment: In your interpretation one would have to suppose the first English means either the language itself, or the people of England. Which makes the whole sentence even more nonsensical, since clearly no native speakers would ever produce the utterance. Also note that (very rarely), "english" is used in the world of snooker to mean the "spin" applied to the cue ball, controlling its final position after a shot. Plausibly it may (even more rarely) function as a verb for applying that spin, though I've never heard it used that way.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, two points. First, how would "own" be explained if we were to use the snooker version of "English"? Secondly, this is an ad, and most ads are nonsensical in their language use.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  it's very interested. I wanted in so feedbacks.

Comment: @Thursagen: I didn't mean to suggest the snooker meaning was relevant here, it was just an interesting aside. Clearly the ad itself is bordering on gibberish, and should simply serve as a warning to anyone wanting to learn English that they should look for teachers with better command of the language.